# Launch a virtual machine remotely with Python VirtualBox API

Tags: python, launch

I'm new to VirtualBox API and I'm trying to launch a virtual machine remotely via VBoxWebSrv.exe, which is running locally (for testing).
I've done this so far:

```
from vboxapi import *
params = {'url' : 'http://localhost:18083',
          'user' : 'user',
          'password' : 'password'
          }
webmgr = VirtualBoxManager('WEBSERVICE', params)
vbox = webmgr.getVirtualBox()
machines = vbox.getMachines()

for mach in machines:
    session = webmgr.getSessionObject(vbox)
    progress = mach.launchVMProcess(session, "gui", "")
```

but it crashes when it comes to the launchVMProcess method. I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\git\VirtualBox-Manager\VirtualBox_Manager\src\test.py", line 45, in <module>
    progress = mach.launchVMProcess(session, "", "")
  File "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\sdk\bindings\webservice\python\lib\VirtualBox_wrappers.py", line 1801, in __getattr__
    return IUnknown.__getattr__(self, name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\sdk\bindings\webservice\python\lib\VirtualBox_wrappers.py", line 388, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

It is weird that this works just fine when I use COM (=without VBoxServer.exe). It seems that the method is not implemented for webservice or there is missing reference to the method or I don't know.

I use the newest SDK (5.0.14) together with VirtualBox 5.0.14 and the host machine is Windows 8.1 64-bit.
Is there any way to solve this?

Thank you very much for any ideas, I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, the webservice of SDK 5.0.14 is bugged and can't be used properly. This issue has been fixed with SDK 5.0.16, which has been released today.